# GitExtensions not respecting .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, git-extensions

I am using Windows 10 64-bit and Git Extensions 2.51.01

I have added the *.gitignore* file from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore to the .gitignore folder in the root of my git repository, including

```
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

And git extensions's commit dialog shows far too many files, including many in bin and obj folders. I don't have the "Show Ignored files" option activated.

These are files that have not been added to the repository and have + icons next to them.

If I use Git Extensions's "add to gitignore" right-click option and then enter bin/ and click "Ignore" I get the following error appear:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path ... is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
at
GitUI.CommandsDialogs.FormAddToGitIgnore.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<AddToIgnoreClick>b__0(String x)
at
GitUI.CommandsDialogs.FormAddToGitIgnore.AddToIgnoreClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Seems like that the whole point of that stacktrace is to answer your question...

Comment: Stacktrace looked pretty useless, but I've added it.

Comment: You might be right, but if it literally says `...`, that's indeed a problem.

Comment: turns out the problem that I had my .gitignore file within a directory called .gitignore, so presumably Git Extensions was trying to edit the "file" (which was actually a directory) called .gitignore and failing, because it wasn't a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` must a file, not a folder. The readme in the https://github.com/github/gitignore actually says that. 
I believe you copy a file from that repo into yours and rename it to `.gitignore`. In Windows Explorer you rename it to `.gitignore.` (note the trailing dot).

You can find detailed info at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore or just google.

Comment: nope, renaming the file to ".gitignore." had no effect.

Comment: doh, I thought for some reason it was supposed to be a file called .gitignore within a folder called .gitignore, works now that I move the file called ".ignore" to the root :)